Ubuntu Docker-compose Error while starting
When I try to start mydocker-compose.yml
I get an Error message which is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 791, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 497, in _make_request
    conn.request(
TypeError: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'

MY docker-compose File looks like this:
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db123
      POSTGRES_USER: user123
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 04Schnuffi09
  app:
    image: my-node-app
    ports:
      - "13000:3000"

I've created my own Dockerfile called my-node-app:
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

I'm running Ubuntu24.04
I tried removing docker and docker-compose and reinstalling it. I tried rebooting my PC. Nothing helps. Any Ideas how to fix this? What can I do?

If you're getting a Python backtrace trying to run Compose, you're running a fairly old version of the Compose tool.  I'd expect it should still work, but that version isn't officially supported any more.  Does upgrading to the newer version of the Compose tool help the problem at all?
